# AWS create_multipart_upload in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create s3 `create_multipart_upload` in AWS Lambda but it does not work:

> "errorMessage": "2021-08-30T09:14:04.681Z 5f57321e-f82d-4f3e-95ac-13cfcaba4af1 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds"

I changed Lambda function timeout but still the same result.

My code:

```
import logging
import boto3
import time

from botocore.client import Config
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'), endpoint_url='https://bucket.enpoint_url')
    
    now_day = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(time.time()))
    
    bucket_name='bucket_name'
    
    object_name = now_day + '/' + event['path']
    
    try:
        response = s3_client.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name)
        result = response
        
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None
   
    return result
```

but if I send a request to generate_presigned_post in my code, I get a response normally

Why does `generate_presigned_post` work and `create_multipart_upload` not?

Additionally remove the endpoint, create_multipart_upload works as well.

```
boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'), endpoint_url='https://bucket.enpoint_url')

->  boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```

I don't know the cause.

Comment: Is it a big upload? If so, you might need to extend the Timeout of the Lambda function to more than 30 seconds. Why are you supplying a `signature_version` and an `endpoint_url`?

Comment: It is correct to create a multipart upload to do a big upload. But when I do create_multipart_upload I get an error.

1.  I tried the timeout for 10 minutes, but it's the same.
2. The reason for using signature_version is that if you don't use it, an error related to "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" will appear.
3. Ultimately, we will send data from a server on-premises via VPN. So I created a VPC private DNS using endpoint-url

For reference, the Internet is not available in ON-PREMISE.

Thanks for the reply